# WP7 image processing API

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, image-processing, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I am trying to find an API for image processing(Threshold, Segmentation n Character matching)  in Windows Phone.I can't find something that will run on WP7

Is there anything out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is none available which can do what you are looking for.

You can take a look at the open source ImageTools library located at Codeplex to start developing your own:  http://imagetools.codeplex.com/documentation

You can also take a look at LEAD Tools Imaging SDK which may provide some help: http://www.leadtools.com/sdk/image-processing/default.htm

Comment: Thank You..i will look into those links